# Casperjs, waitfor not executing then()

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to click elements on casperjs based on coordinates, the clicks sometimes fail because for example a link could have a line-break which makes the random coordinates I get try to click like in the bottom left corner where there's no clickable element (even when the x,y,x+width,y+height bounds are correct). So I am trying to detect when the link fails and when it succeed.

I tried this code:

```
var oldUrl;

casper.start( url, function ( ) {

    oldUrl = casper.getCurrentUrl();

    // code that clicks element based on coordinates
    
}).then( function() {

    
    casper.waitFor(function check() {
        return oldUrl === casper.getCurrentUrl();
    }, function then() {
        require('utils').dump( 'link click succeed' );
    }, function timeout() { 
        require('utils').dump( 'link click failed' );
    }, 5000);
    
}).run();
```

Also tried without the first then() and using waitFor directly after start like `.start(...).waitFor(...)`. I also tried this code I found googling:

```
casper.waitForUrlChange = function(then, onTimeout, timeout){
    var oldUrl;
    this.then(function(){
        oldUrl = this.getCurrentUrl();
    }).waitFor(function check(){
        return oldUrl === this.getCurrentUrl();
    }, then, onTimeout, timeout);
    return this;
};

casper.start( url, function ( ) {

    // code that clicks element based on coordinates
    
}).waitForUrlChange( function then() {
        require('utils').dump( 'link clicked succeed' );
    }, function timeout() { 
        require('utils').dump( 'link click failed' );
    }, 5000);
}).run();
```

When I use some random coordinates to make sure the click fail, I get this on the output:

> [warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
>
> link click failed

But when I use real coordinates making sure the click succeed, I never get `link clicked succeed` on the output, the script just clicks the element, then goes to "about:blank" and exits.

How do I make it to execute the "then()" function when the click element succeeds?

Comment: You've never said what is supposed to happen when a click is successful. Is there a page load? Does something change on the page? Is something added or removed from localStorage?

Comment: If you assume that a click leads to a page load, your test cases are flipped. If the current page URL is the old page URL, then I suppose the click was unsuccessful and the output should be 'link click failed' and not 'link clicked succeed'

Comment: @ArtjomB. When the click succeeds it loads a new page with a different url, and then is where I would want it to show "link click succeed".

Comment: So, you've got your cases wrong: `oldUrl === casper.getCurrentUrl()` should be `oldUrl !== casper.getCurrentUrl()`